# Weird behaviour of jquery-ui-tabs in chrome (linux)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a problem using jquery-ui-tabs under chrome linux on this site: http://www.relaxacion.com

I can switch between tabs without problem by clicking on the thumbnails on the right of the video area, but from time to time (unfortunately, I don't even know what triggers this behaviour: I just load the page and click the tabs and sometimes it happens and sometimes i doesn't) when I hover on the video area it flips out and shows a different tab instead. This ghost tab is over the selected tab and I can't see it but when I click on the tab area I'm acting on this actual selected tab below, not the one I see. If I scroll down the page and up again it shows the right tab again ¿?oO'

I searched jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-tabs documentation and I can't find any related bugs. I also tried to deactivate any other jquery plugins and manually loading jquery-ui-tabs and its dependencies from google repository instead of using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');` wordpress feature.

I tested the HTML and CSS using the W3C tools, and everything seems fine, so I guess it should be a JS issue, but the console doesn't show any info. What am I doing wrong? How can I trace the problem if I don't even know how to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed a similar issue with chrome on linux (or OS X). For my issue at least, there was a chrome plugin/extension that was causing the issue. Not sure exactly which one, but when I went back to a vanilla install of chrome I no longer seem to have the issues. Cheers!

Comment: No plugin problem here, but something very similar. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

After careful review I found out about a few unrelated javascript errors on the same page. Whenever an action triggered any of these errors the tabs functionality presented the described problem (maybe the event handling propagation chain was broken?). Fixing these bugs also fixed this issue, so everything is fine now.